# How to get Runtime types and Runtime (PalletCustomOrigins) from subxt metadata.scale

Tags: subxt, metadata, origin

The main aim is to get Governance Origins using subxt from the encoded metadata

Answer (score 2):

This can be accessed using the following syntax

`#[subxt::subxt(runtime_metadata_path = "testmetadata.scale")] pub mod runtime {}`

Then access runtime types, Note: use subxt-cli to generate metadata.json so that you can easily see the path.

Then, `runtime::runtime_types::kusama_runtime::governance::origins::pallet_custom_origins::Origin::{BigSpender,SmallSpender,....};`

```
<metadata>::<runtime_types>::<kusama_runtime>::<pallet>::<types>::<follow the path>;
```

Hopefully it helps to access runtime_types , such as weightV2, Origins, Calls ..etc